# How can I contain elements of a D3 animation within a predefined container?

Tags: animation, d3.js

I've been experimenting with this example:

http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/collision.html

This is the first time I've ever looked at D3.  I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.  Basically all I want to do is put the balls in the example above inside of this:

http://www.clker.com/cliparts/p/8/g/0/D/T/black-empty-flask.svg

I want the balls to move around but stay within the flask.  I'm beginning to think this is not an easy task for a jQuery developer with no real svg experience.  Is that true?

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 4):

EDIT:

I have done this example:

http://bl.ocks.org/rveciana/6220206

Some improvements are needed with the collisions, and the shape must be made of lines (not Bezier lines, to make easier to calculate the reflection).

I hope that is helps.

Comment: Nice example - it's just a shame the code is lacking some comments to explain.

Comment: Is there example for v4? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know. But the changes should be small. Anyway, the example was quite buggy...

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be too hard to achieve even with no D3 experience. The difficult part is that you need to check yourself whether a given coordinate is inside or outside the flask. Assuming the existence of such a function, say `isContained`, the only change you need to make is to the `tick` event handler function that places the bubbles.

```
force.on("tick", function(e) {
  var q = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes),
      i = 0,
      n = nodes.length;

  while (++i < n) {
    q.visit(collide(nodes[i]));
  }

  svg.selectAll("circle")
      .filter(function(d) { return isContained(d.x, d.y); })
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

   svg.selectAll("circle")
      .filter(function(d) { return !isContained(d.x, d.y); })
      .each(function(d) {
        d.x = d3.select(this).attr("cx");
        d.y = d3.select(this).attr("cy");
      });
});
```

The first part of the handler is unchanged, but in the second part only the coordinates of those circles that will still be contained within the flask (using `isContained`) are updated. That is, any circles that would be moved outside of the flask remain where they are.

For the circles that would not be contained any longer, the position set by the force layout is reset to the previous one (where the circles are drawn).